How to find objects from Memory tab in Chrome
I am trying to relate some findings from a memory snapshot back to my code. For example, on the following picture it shows Array with symbol @ followed by the number. If that is an object's id, how can I find it in the code while debugging it? Please share any idea.


This question is similar to: How can I get the memory address of a JavaScript variable?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
